# In ArrayDeque containsAll(Collection c), contains(Object o), equals(Object o) give expected but equals(Collection c) gives unexpected result

Tags: java, collections, overriding, equals, arraydeque

I have the following "Person" `class` -

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    Person(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person person) {
        int myReturn = 0;
        int minLength = 0;
        boolean equal = false;
        int id1 = id;
        int id2 = person.id;
        String name1 = name;
        String name2 = person.name;

        if (name1.length() > name2.length()) {
            minLength = name2.length();
        } else if (name1.length() < name2.length()) {
            minLength = name1.length();
        } else {
            minLength = name1.length();
            equal = true;
        }

        if (id1 > id2) {
            myReturn = 1;
        } else if (id1 < id2) {
            myReturn = -1;
        } else {
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < minLength; i++) {
                if (name1.charAt(i) > name2.charAt(i)) {
                    myReturn = 1;
                    break;
                } else if (name1.charAt(i) < name2.charAt(i)) {
                    myReturn = -1;
                    break;
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
            }
            if(i == minLength) {
                if (equal) {
                    myReturn = 0;
                } else if (name1.length() > minLength) {
                    myReturn = 1;
                } else {
                    myReturn = -1;
                }
            }
        }
        return myReturn;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Person person = (Person) obj;
        return id == person.id && Objects.equals(name, person.name);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, name);
    }
}
```

Now the following codes behave as expected -

Code 1:

```
/* equals(Object object) - method */
        Person person3 = new Person(2, "Neha");
        Person person4 = new Person(2, "Neha");
        Person person5 = new Person(2, "Sneha");
        System.out.println(person3.equals(person4));
        System.out.println(person3.equals(person5));
```

Output -

```
true
false
```

Code 2:

```
/* contains(Object object) - method */
        ArrayDeque<Person> arrayDeque13 = new ArrayDeque<>(List.of(
                new Person(99, "Needhi"),
                new Person(12, "Papori"),
                new Person(78, "Pallavi")
        ));
        Person person1 = new Person(12, "Papori");
        Person person2 = new Person(13, "Puja");
        System.out.println(arrayDeque13.contains(person1));
        System.out.println(arrayDeque13.contains(person2));
```

Output -

```
true
false
```

Code 3:

```
/* containsAll(Collection collection) - method */
        ArrayDeque<Person> arrayDeque14 = new ArrayDeque<>(List.of(
                new Person(3, "Namita"),
                new Person(2, "Mridu"),
                new Person(82, "Priyadarshini"),
                new Person(89, "Tina"),
                new Person(13, "Kajal")
        ));
        ArrayDeque<Person> arrayDeque15 = new ArrayDeque<>(List.of(
                new Person(3, "Namita"),
                new Person(2, "Mridu"),
                new Person(13, "Kajal")
        ));
        ArrayDeque<Person> arrayDeque16 = new ArrayDeque<>(List.of(
                new Person(3, "Namita"),
                new Person(2, "Mridu"),
                new Person(13, "Neha")
        ));
        System.out.println(arrayDeque14.containsAll(arrayDeque15));
        System.out.println(arrayDeque14.containsAll(arrayDeque16));
```

Output -

```
true
false
```

But the following code doesn't behave as expected -

Code 4:

```
/* equals(Collection collection) - method */
        ArrayDeque<Person> arrayDeque17 = new ArrayDeque<>(List.of(
                new Person(56, "Leena"),
                new Person(66, "Nidhi"),
                new Person(76, "Payal")
        ));
        ArrayDeque<Person> arrayDeque18 = new ArrayDeque<>(List.of(
                new Person(56, "Leena"),
                new Person(66, "Nidhi"),
                new Person(76, "Payal")
        ));
        ArrayDeque<Person> arrayDeque19 = new ArrayDeque<>(List.of(
                new Person(56, "Leena"),
                new Person(66, "Nidhi"),
                new Person(76, "Payel")
        ));
        System.out.println(arrayDeque17.equals(arrayDeque18));
        System.out.println(arrayDeque17.equals(arrayDeque19));
```

Output -

```
false
false
```

Here, I expect first output to be `true` but it is `false`

As given in -

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html

> Methods inherited from interface java.util.Collection
> addAll, containsAll, equals, hashCode, removeAll, retainAll

So, where am I going wrong?

Comment: [`ArrayDeque`](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk11/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayDeque.java) doesn't implement `equals`, so it uses the default implementation from `Object`

Comment: And `Collection` (or any of the implemented interfaces) doesn't declare a default `equals` method either, nor does the direct ancestor of `ArrayDequeue` (that is `AbstractCollection`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the commenters have already mentioned, `ArrayDeque` does not implement `equals()`. If unsure, look at the javadoc and search for "equals". If it's under "Methods inherited from class java.lang.Object" then you know it's using `Object`'s `equals` implementation:

[image]

Interfaces **cannot** have an `equals()` method implementation since Java does not allow a `default` equals method. If a class implements multiple interfaces, each containing a default "equals" methods, which one should be used? So it's kind of irrelevant that it is inherited from the `Collection` interface. Javadoc lists it there because the `Collection` interface excplicitly defines `equals()` with a collection-specific javadoc.